# Problema ao renomear os arquivos Bundle

Tags: css, bundle

Alterei os nomes do Bundle da minha aplicação, porém quando rodo ela novamente, ele tenta acessar o mesmo caminho com os nomes antigos do Bundle. Por exemplo, antes o nome do bundle era ("bundles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"), então modifiquei para ("bundles/css/bootstrap.css"), porém quando eu executo a aplicação ele continua procurando os arquivos no caminho antigo.

Nota: Já limpei o cache do navegador, mudei o EnableOptimization no Global.asax tanto para true quanto para false e já resetei as configurações do site no IIS.

Não tenho ideia de como resolver isso.

Comment: Mas no seu arquivo html onde você referencia o mesmo, você já mudou o nome?

Comment: Sim Leonardo, eu alterei todas as referências, mas continua zuado